# python iterate through a list and skip n iterations within the loop every time a condition is met

Tags: python, list, loops

the following code iterates through a list and counts every time the condition `<10` is met.
What I want to do is that once this condition is met, the next point that needs to be tested is `numlist[4]-numlist[i-4]` having an index that is double of the starting point, and if the condition is met again, the next number tested should have an index that is double the previous one: `numlist[8]-numlist[i-8]` and so on. Is there a way to do so ?
This code

```
numlist=[10,15,18,20,22,24,32,40, 42, 45]
print(numlist)
count=0
countlist=[]
starting_point=2
for i in range(starting_point,len(numlist)):
    if numlist[i]-numlist[i-starting_point] < 10:
        print(numlist[i],'-',numlist[i-2],'=',numlist[i]-numlist[i-2])
        count+=1
        countlist.append(count)
print('counts =', countlist[-1])
```

prints out

```
[10, 15, 18, 20, 22, 24, 32, 40, 42, 45]
18 - 10 = 8
20 - 15 = 5
22 - 18 = 4
24 - 20 = 4
45 - 40 = 5
counts = 5
```

but what I want it to print out is:

```
[10, 15, 18, 20, 22, 24, 32, 40, 42, 45]
18 - 10 = 8
24 - 15 = 9
counts = 2
```

Comment: in this task, the starting point is crucial, I am not sure a while loop will be well suited for it. However, if you have an idea in how to use it, I'll be happy to check it out

Comment: Try doubling the starting point variable in your `if` block and using the starting point in your print instead of `2`. You could also double your `i`.

Comment: that doesn't work as it doesn't even print what is supposed to print

Comment: I have it working in [online-Python](https://www.online-python.com/gj2Ts3xeVN).